# What will replace Beans Binding in Java 7?

Tags: java, beans-binding

I read somewhere - the link escapes me - that Beans Binding will not be a part of Java 7. Does anybody know what will replace it?

Also, are there any alternatives to beans binding in the current release of Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend [JGoodies Binding](https://binding.dev.java.net/) for fields and [Glazed Lists](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists) for collections.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt anything would replace it if it won't be part of Java 7, it's probably more like it did not make it and will be added later (though I don't know any specifics). Some ideas:

- You could use [beans binding](https://beansbinding.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList) with Java 5 or higher (even if it won't be part of Java 7)
- If Swing is no requirement, you might consider [JFace data binding](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/JFace_Data_Binding)